# I want to draw square symbol in google map polyline symbol

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to draw the square symbol for google map polyline but I am not getting a symbol path for the square,
this path I am using but does not create a square symbol
could someone please help

> const lineSymbol = {
> path: "M24 0h-24v24h24v-24zz",
> strokeOpacity: 1,
> strokeColor: "#ABABAB",
> scale: 3,
> rotation: 65,
> strokeWeight: 5,   };

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2ipw.png)

Answer (score 0):

after looking multiple resources finally, I found the path to write the square symbol below I am sharing the code
thanks to
https://javascript.tutorialink.com/google-map-marker-customization-by-google-maps-symbolpath-circle/

> ```
>   const lineSymbol = {
>      path: 'M -2,0 0,-2 2,0 0,2 z',
>     strokeColor: "#ABABAB",
>      fillColor: "#ABABAB", 
>     fillOpacity:1,
>      scale: 3, 
>      rotation: 55,
>      strokeWeight: 1,
>   };
> ```